# Java 'ext' directory versus -Xbootclasspath/p:

Tags: java

I want to make use of the JSR166 facilities in Java 6. So I've downloaded the jar.

I'd like to make this process (relatively) painless. I was perplexed to discover that adding it to the ext directory in my Mac's JDK/JRE (or to /Library/Java/extensions) did not work.

Only -Xbootclasspath did the trick.

Why is this? Are exts somehow defined more narrowly?

Answer (score 1):

Installing JAR's into the extension directory makes them just as available to use as including them via the `-Xbootclasspath` option. In terms of load order you have this:

1. Bootstrap class path. This is controlled by the JVM provider, and
   can be overridden with the (non-standard) `-Xbootclasspath` command
   line option.
2. Extension folder - JAR's in this folder are loaded and scoped with
   the same availability as bootstrap classes.
3. User classes - User classes are loaded from the sources defined via
   the class path property. This is by default specified by the
   `CLASSPATH` environment variable but can be overridden by the
   standard `-cp` command line option.

Any classes found in the bootstrap class path or loaded as an extension should be immediately available to your program.

You can easily verify this on your Mac. Compile the following:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

And in a command console:

```
javac Test.java
jar cvf test.jar Test.class
cp test.jar /Library/Java/Extensions
rm Test.class test.jar
java Test
```

And of course the result will be `'Hello World'` printed to your console.

Check to make sure you were invoking the right class from your JAR, and that it was actually placed in the right extension folder.

Comment: So if I needed p: on the bootclasspath then the extension folder isn't going to work, because it will come second?

Comment: Not correct, both the -Xbootclasspath and extension folder are scanned for classes to load at startup. What is p:?

Comment: Read the doc on -Xbootclasspath. You tell it whether to insert at the front, the back, or instead. with /a: or /p: etc.